# how an $m×n$ matrix can be obtained from an $m×m$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to teach my self linear algebra from Hoffman's book and I can't understand how could an $m×n$ matrix can be obtained from an $m×m$ matrix as they are different in columns

the 3 row operation are

1- multiplying a row with a constant doesn't equal zero

2- adding a certain row multiplied a row with a constant doesn't equal zero to another row

3- swap 2 rows

and non of that can change the number of columns
[image]

Comment: Probably a typo in the book.

Comment: I am sure this is a misprint, and it was supposed to say $m\times m$ both times.

Comment: Even if it were a typo, the statement is still consistent.  It just happens to be that all $m\times n$ matrices where $m\neq n$ are not elementary.